# How to get "old" value when observing realm List type by kvo

Tags: ios, swift, realm, key-value-observing

I need observe realm object's List type value.

I need to access new and old value when the observer is called.

The problem is that a cannot access "old" value in observeValueForKeyPath function.

If I log "change" in that function, it shows following instead of conventional "Old" & "New".

```
Optional(["new": <__NSArrayI 0x7fcc8bc57150>(
User {
}
)
, "indexes": <_NSCachedIndexSet: 0x7fcc8bc07970>[number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (1)], "kind": 2])
```

What does those mean and how can I access "old" value?

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ValueContainer: Object {
    let users = List<User>()
}

class User: Object {

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let container = ValueContainer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        container.users.appendContentsOf([User(), User(), User(), User()])

        container.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "users", options: [.New, .Old], context: nil)

    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

        print("---- Observer called ---")
        print("KeyPath:\(keyPath)")

        guard let container = object as? ValueContainer else {
            print("Object cast failed")
            return
        }

        print("Change")
        print(change)

    }


    @IBAction func buttonTap(sender: AnyObject) {
        container.users.insert(User(), atIndex: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you actually add the objects to Realm. You are just observing a collection property of an Object, so you get back in the `change` param the changes to the collection and not to individual elements.

Comment: I need to observe a realm Object model whether it it saved to realm or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend a good read of the docs about Realm KVO [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#key-value-observation). You'll notice that adding observers to an unmanaged object (not added to Realm yet) and then adding the object to the DB is not possible, so you'll want to design your observing strategy based on that:

> Observing properties of unmanaged instances of Object subclasses works
>   just like with any other dynamic property, but note that you cannot
>   add an object to a Realm (with realm.add(obj) or other similar
>   methods) while it has any registered observers.

Another key takeaway from the quote above is that observing an unmanaged Realm model object is nothing different than observing a "normal" non-Realm object. In your example is this exactly what you do, as you don't add any of your objects to the DB.

So, you are KVO observing a collection (`users`) and you'll get notifications each time something is added to the collection but it will be about the changed collection and not the new values of the objects in the collection.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    print(change?[.indexesKey])
    print(change?[.newKey])
}
```

In the exemple above `.indexesKey` refers to the index of the newly added object and `.newKey` refers to the newly added object.

If you change the value of a property of an object in the collection, you won't be notified at all !

To get this kind of notification you'll have to observe each object in the collection.